# A source for the suggestion that Moshe Rabbeinu was raised in the house of Pharaoh so that he would see real Malchus

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, malchut-royalty, parashas-shemos

A speaker remarked that the Divine plan called for Moshe to be raised in the house of Pharaoh so that he (Moshe) would see real Malchus. To me the suggestion seemed to be that in some way Pharaoh was a good role model for Moshe eventually to imitate.

This seems strange to me.

What are some sources that make this suggestion?

Comment: There is a Mitzva to go see non Jewish royalty seemingly for a similar sort of reason. This doesn't answer your question but it makes the suggestion perhaps more palatable

Comment: Moshe Rabbeinu's upbringing in the House of Pharaoh also made it to where he was familiar with Egyptian government protocol for when he would storm into the palace later and demand to let the Israelites go.

Comment: Ibn Ezra on Shemot 2:3 says something along these lines. Not sure if it’s quite what you’re looking for though